# Regex wont understand white space

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

Have code:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z\-\s]", "g");
val = val.replace(regexp,'');
```

It need too leave letters (*a-zA-Z*), - (*\-*) and white spaces (*\s*) and remove all other symbols.

But now it remove white spaces too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double the backslashes:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z\\-\\s]", "g");
```

or, better, use a regex literal (and simplify it):

```
var regexp = /[^a-z\s-]/gi;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your slashes need to be escaped in a string literal.

A simple solution is to use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z\-\s]/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[JavaScript Regex Generator tool](http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php)** i came across if anyone is interested.

Was quite useful for regex amateurs like me.